# VPN Server with site CNAME

Tags: domain-name-system, vpn, cname-record

I have set up a VPN server on my router and set a subdomain from my website (ex. vpn.mywebsite.com) that forwards my dynamic DNS address, so when I connect to my VPN, my server is vpn.mywebsite.com and username and pass.

My question is, is there a way so I can make it when I go to vpn.mywebsite.com from the browser, it displays an instructional message? I am not sure how to do this since I have a CNAME that sends vpn.mywebsite.com to my VPN server for easier access but at the same time, I want it so that when a user goes to vpn.mywebsite.com from a browser gets an instructional message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could proxy/port forward the port 80 traffic from vpn.example.com to example.com.

Comment: I am not sure if godaddy (where the website is hosted) will let me port forward! Will try this and get back to you.

Comment: This did not work! I can not do any port forwarding with godaddy!

Comment: @unknownsolo: use a proxy server.